# How do I start a module in google app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm struggling to start a module. Basically I want to make a request here:

```
http://[modulename].[appname].appspot.com
```

Which works, as I have my `[modulename].yaml` correctly configured to map any request (/*) to the backend script I want to run.

How can I make that call from a cron job? I tried this and it doesn't seem to work:

```
url = "http://[modulename].[appname].appspot.com"
result = urlfetch.fetch(url)
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's anything like how it used to be before Modules, you have to start them "by hand" from the command line with `appcfg`.

```
appcfg.py [options] start <app-directory>
```

That will start the specified module version.

More details here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp

Comment: Huh -- is there no way load a module within my app? I.e. having a script within my cron.yaml open a module?

Comment: not sure, not using modules yet, but starting them is a one time thing, different to addressing requests to them.